# Projection of u onto v and v onto u

Tags: calculus, vectors

Given the vector u = $<-2, 6, 4>$ and a vector v such that the vector projection of u onto v is $<2,4,4>$, and the vector projection of v onto u is $<−8,24,16>$. What is the vector v?

I tried it like this but can't reach to final answer.

[image]

Comment: You should use the command `\langle` and `rangle` to correctly type $\langle, \rangle$, although it seems rare to use these for vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection of $\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}\v u$ onto $\v v$ is a scalar times $\v v$.  So from the given information we have
$$\v v=\lambda(2,4,4)\ .$$
Hence
$${\rm proj}_{\v u}\v v=\frac{\v v\cdot\v u}{\v u\cdot\v u}\,\v u
  =\lambda\frac{9}{14}(-2,6,4)\ .$$
It is given that this projection is $(-8,24,16)$, so $\lambda=\frac{56}9$ and hence
$$\v v=\tfrac{56}9(2,4,4)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more tangent way to solve this problem:

Notice $v$ and the projection of $u$ onto $v$ must have the same direction, therefore we can assume 
$$v = \lambda(2, 4, 4),$$
in which $\lambda$ is a constant to be determined. Now use the other condition to establish the equation 
$$(-8, 24, 16) = \frac{\langle v, u \rangle}{\langle u, u \rangle}u = \frac{36\lambda}{56}(-2, 6, 4).$$
Solve this to get $\lambda = \frac{56}{9}$. Therefore,
$$v = \frac{56}{9}(2, 4, 4).$$